Is there a way to find the intersection volume of 2 entities?
I'm wondering whether there's a method to find the intersection volume between 2 entities in Realitykit in VisionOS 1 or 2. For example, take Entity A and Entity B, their intersection volume would be represented by C... is there a way to find the volume of C?

Is there any tangible way to achieve this or is this not currently possible on Vision Pro devices? I think the main challenge here is to the find the intersecting mesh between the two entities. The mesh volume then can be calculated using a version of this C# code

RealityKit 4.0 API doesn't have a Boolean Intersection Op available. But Euclid package does.
